# Does omnifaces have pagination related components?

Tags: jsf, pagination, omnifaces

I searched in omnifaces' showcase without success for any component that helps with JSF (datatable) real pagination.

Do you guys know if there is any?

It would be a great feature.

I worked a bit the aproach taken here https://rogerkeays.com/blog/paging-large-data-sets-with-a-lazylist and came with the code below.

It's very generic and could be used with any JSF component library or persistence API.

The developer must implement the lazy list in his JSF managed bean (backing bean), which has access to the business facade or entity manager to do the queries.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public abstract class AbstractLazyList extends AbstractList {

/**
 * Current page cache.
 */
private final Map<Integer, Object> currentPage = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();

/**
 * Page size. Default 50.
 */
private int pageSize = 50;

public void setPageSize(int pageSize) {
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
}

@Override
public Object get(int index) {
    if (currentPage.containsKey(index)) {
        return currentPage.get(index);
    }

    queryNewPage(index);

    return currentPage.get(index);
}

/**
 * Clears cache and queries new page's itens.
 * 
 * @param firstItemIndex
 *            first item index
 */
private void queryNewPage(int firstItemIndex) {
    currentPage.clear();
    final List<Object> pageResults = queryNextPage(firstItemIndex, pageSize);
    for (int j = 0; j < pageResults.size(); j++) {
        currentPage.put(firstItemIndex + j, pageResults.get(j));
    }
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return queryResultsSize();
}

/**
 * Queries next page itens.
 * 
 * @param firstRowIndex
 *            first row index
 * @param pageSize
 *            maximum resuts of the query
 * @return list of results
 */
protected abstract List<Object> queryNextPage(int firstRowIndex,
        int pageSize);

/**
 * Counts the total results of the query.
 * 
 * @return query's total results
 */
protected abstract int queryResultsSize();
}
}
```

Maybe an aproach like this could fit in omnifaces.

Answer (score 2):

OmniFaces is not geared to visually oriented UI components, but more to utilities which do its work "behind the scenes" and can be used in combination with any other JSF component library.

Consider looking at visually oriented UI component libraries such as PrimeFaces and RichFaces. They offer data table components with pagination possibilities.

- [PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>` showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf)
- [RichFaces `<rich:dataTable>`+`<rich:dataScroller>` showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataScroller&skin=blueSky)

Comment: I was thinking in a more generic solution to the real pagination issue http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/lazy-loading-jsf-datatable/ More specifically, I was thinking about lazyLists.

Comment: I updated the question to be more clear about what I meant with lazylists.